# setTimeout not working in recursive algorithm: React setState Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, settimeout, setstate

I am a beginner in coding and am trying to code a Sudoku solving visualizer in react with a recursive backtracking algorithm.

Here's my code:

```
class Sudoku extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            board: [
                [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
                [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
                [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
                [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
                [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
                [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
                [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
                [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
                [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
            ],
            displayBoard: [
                [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
                [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
                [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
                [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
                [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
                [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
                [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
                [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
                [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
            ],
            steps: []
        };
        this.solve = this.solve.bind(this);
        this.findEmpty = this.findEmpty.bind(this);
        this.valid = this.valid.bind(this);
        this.run = this.run.bind(this);
    }
    
    run(){
        if (this.solve()) {
            console.log(this.state.steps,this.state.board)
            var objThis = this;
            for (var i in this.state.steps){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    objThis.setState({
                        displayBoard: objThis.state.steps[i]
                    });
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    }

    findEmpty(){
        for (var i in [...Array(this.state.board.length).keys()]){
            for (var j in [...Array(this.state.board[0].length).keys()]){
                if (this.state.board[i][j] == ""){
                    return [parseInt(i),parseInt(j)]
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
        
    solve(){
        var find = this.findEmpty()
        if (!(find)){
            return true
        }
        else{
            var row = find[0]
            var col = find[1]
        }
        for (var i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]){
            if (this.valid(i,[row,col])){
                var newboard = this.state.board
                newboard[row][col] = i
                
                
                this.setState({
                    steps: newboard
                });
                
                this.setState({
                    board: newboard
                });
                console.log(1,this.state.steps,this.state.board)
                if (this.solve()){
                    return true
                }
                var newboard = this.state.board
                newboard[row][col] = 0
                this.setState({
                    steps: newboard
                });
  
                this.setState({
                    board: newboard
                });
                console.log(2,this.state.steps,this.state.board)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    valid(num,pos){
        for (var i in [...Array(this.state.board.length).keys()]){
            i = parseInt(i)
            if ((this.state.board[pos[0]][i] == num) && (pos[1] != i)){            
                return false
            }    
        }
        for (var i in [...Array(this.state.board.length).keys()]){
            i = parseInt(i)
            if ((this.state.board[i][pos[1]] == num) && (pos[0] != i)){            
                return false
            }            
        }
        var box_x = Math.floor(pos[1] / 3)
        var box_y = Math.floor(pos[0] / 3)
        var j
        for (i=box_y*3; i<box_y*3 + 3; i++){
            for (j=box_x*3; j<box_x*3 + 3; j++){
                if ((this.state.board[i][j] == num) && ((i,j) != pos)){   
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }


    render() {
        var divs = []
        for (var x in this.state.displayBoard){
            for (var y in this.state.displayBoard){
                divs.push(<div>{this.state.displayBoard[x][y]}</div>)
            }
        }
        return(
            <div>
            <div id="sudoku">{divs}</div>  
            <button id="solve" onClick={this.run}>Solve!</button>  
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Sudoku />, document.getElementById('target'));
```

As you can see I would like to have a delay before each number is displayed. However, my code does nothing the first time i click on "Solve!", then displays the whole solution without delay on second click. Console shows that this.state.steps is an empty array on first click and the entire solved board on second click. Clearly, the setState() for steps in the solve() function is not working.

May I ask is there another way to do this? Or can my code be fixed?

Apologies if my code is inefficient or unorganized as I am just a beginner.

Comment: This seems a bit complicated for a beginner.

Comment: I watched a tutorial for the Sudoku backtracking algorithm and just have to implement it with react so it's not as complicated as it seems I guess.

Comment: You're invoking the timeouts outside solve, it will run the entire recursion to the end without invoking the timeouts.